# Why are compilers non-reentrant at the beginning?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I'm reading some yacc and lex related stuff and some other compiler implementations, it seems like they are all using global state and hence really unsafe to use multithreaded situations so it is hard to embed them in other programs. I know GNU Bison and Flex could be used for re-entrancy but why are they not on by default?

Comment: FWIW, questions like this are generally closed because they are seeking opinions rather than statements of objective fact.

Comment: Have you tried [lemon parser](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/)? That's at least covered in a single `struct` and you pass that around without global data. It's almost similar to Bison syntax too.

Answer (score 2):

Because when the interface for Lex and Yacc was defined, many many many years ago, the use of globals was much more common. Reentrancy changes the interface, and the reentrant interfaces have never been formally standardised (which is probably just as well, given the state of play). At the time, multithreading was not very common, largely because a typical computer just barely had the resources to do one compilation (and sometimes not even that; it was also pretty common for compilation passes to be sequentially loaded executables).

So the default continues to be the non-reentrant, standardised interface. And it probably will remain that way, whether or not we like it.